# Django : How to generate multiple times the same form on a page?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I have to allow a user to register multiple participants to an event based on the number of participants that the user entered before.

To make it clear :

Event A :
X participants

--> X forms must be generated on the next page.

So my code on the next view looks like this :

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for i in range(0, quantity - 1):
            eventParticipant_form = EventForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

            if eventParticipant_form.is_valid():
                participant = eventParticipant_form.save(commit=False)
                participant.customer = customer
                participant.customerOrder = customerOrder
                participant.event = product
                participant.save()
```

The problem is that it only save the last form that i fill. It make sens i think as if even if I generate X eventParticipant_form the form is not saved after.

I don't really see how to do it the proper way. Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: With FormSets: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: Hello, thanks this is exactly what i needed.

Comment: hi, when i try to save my formset it doesnt work. I found why but i dont understand it.
Like in a normal form if i want to assign a foreign key like i do in my example 
``` participant.customer = customer ``` it's working but when it comes to a formset i found that it raise an error : 'list' object has no attribute 'customer'.

I dont understand how my forms turns to be a list.

Comment: if you save a formset, you retrieve the list of all the instances from the forms. So you will need a loop to set the `customer` to all these objects.

Comment: Oh it's working perfectly. Thanks a lot !